# How to pass value as "False" for ManualDiscount when place sales order through web API

Tags: acumatica

I was trying to place sales order through Web API and wanted to uncheck the "Manual Discount" checkbox so I tried to use following code:

```
        SO301000Content SO301000 = context.SO301000GetSchema();
        context.SO301000Clear();

        List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();

        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "SO", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType });
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "<NEW>", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr });
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.OrderCustomerInfo.AcctCD, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Customer });
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.OrderLocationInfo.ID, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Location });

        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.ShippingTotal.ToString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.Totals.PremiumFreight });

        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "30D", LinkedCommand = SO301000.FinancialSettingsFinancialInformation.Terms});
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.PromoCode, LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.DiscountCode });


        //add line items
        foreach (OrderItem item in orderInfo.OrderItems)
        {
            cmds.Add(SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow);
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = item.InventoryCD, LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = item.Quantity.ToString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "Server", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Warehouse });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "False", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.ManualDiscount});
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "Discount1", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.DiscountCode});
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "20", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.DiscountPercent });                
        }

        cmds.Add(SO301000.Actions.Save);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderTotal);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.TaxTotal);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.Location);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.Customer);

        SO301000Content[] SO30100content = context.SO301000Submit(cmds.ToArray());
        .......................
```

however, after the sales order is placed, I found the "Manual Discount" checkbox was still checked and discount I have set to automatically be applied was not applied at all.

I found an old thread about this issue at http://forum.acumatica.com/forum/acumatica-reseller-and-isv-community/development-and-customization/895-order-creation-through-soap-call-with-manual-discosunt-false-not-working, in which a guy said this was a bug, however, that was about 3 years ago. so I assume this bug should have been fixed already...if it is not bug any more, can somebody tell me what I did wrong?

Thanks.

Just did more testing following the suggestion from @Gabriel but the "Manual Discount" was still checked after the order is placed through web service, however, when I tried to place a new order through screen and add same item, the "Manual Discount" was not checked by default. I don't know what was wrong in my code.

Here is the code I just tried and no luck to get discount automatically applied:

```
        SO301000Content SO301000 = context.SO301000GetSchema();
        context.SO301000Clear();

        List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();

        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "SO", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType });
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "<NEW>", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr });
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.OrderCustomerInfo.AcctCD, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Customer });
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.OrderLocationInfo.ID, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Location });

        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.ShippingTotal.ToString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.Totals.PremiumFreight });

        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "30D", LinkedCommand = SO301000.FinancialSettingsFinancialInformation.Terms});
        //cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.PromoCode, LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.DiscountCode });


        //add line items
        foreach (OrderItem item in orderInfo.OrderItems)
        {
            cmds.Add(SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow);
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = item.InventoryCD, LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = item.Quantity.ToString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity });
            //cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "Server", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Warehouse });
            //cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "False", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.ManualDiscount});
            //cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "VOLWHMIS", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.DiscountCode});
            //cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "100", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.DiscountPercent });                
        }

        cmds.Add(SO301000.Actions.Save);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderTotal);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.TaxTotal);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.Location);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.Customer);

        SO301000Content[] SO30100content = context.SO301000Submit(cmds.ToArray());
```

Comment: Could you provide the rest of the code for the line items? Manual discount may be set to true by system based on other fields you set there. Just setting quantity and inventory CD shouldn't make it TRUE however, and you would have no need to set it to False anywhere. Have you tried commenting the rest of the code?

Comment: @Gabriel, I have added those lines to my code. Please note the discount works when I explicitly passed "Discount Code" or "Discount Percentage" as shown in my code, however, that doesn't change the fact that "Manual Discount" checkbox is still checked after the sales order is completed. My goal is to automatically get discount code applied without explicitly passing either code or percentage through API, since that discount code was set to automatically apply to a certain group of products and I thought if I could somehow set "Manual Discount" to false I should get it work as I expect.

Comment: Setting the discount percentage or the discount code on the screen will automatically check Manual Discount. Are you doing that because the discount don't get automatically set? Are they set automatically if you add a similar order from the screen?

Comment: Yes, I explicitly added "discount code" and "discount percentage" in my code after I couldn't get discount automatically applied I guess because the "ManualDiscount" by default is on, although I explicitly set it to "False". The discount has been set up in Acumatica to automatically be applied when a certain product item is in the order. On the screen, I could manually check/uncheck the "Manual Discount" checkbox and when I unchecked the checkbox, the discount was automatically applied.

Comment: There's nothing in the code which should make ManualDiscount on by default - if you just set InventoryID and quantity, does system set it on???

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I initially did but the "ManualDiscount" checkbox was always checked after the order, however, if I add same order through screen, that "Manual Discount" checkbox was not checked and the discount was automatically applied. @Gabriel, please take a look at my code I just added above.

Comment: OK, i'm checking it out - will keep you updated

Comment: I replicated your issue, still investigating why ManualDiscount is set to TRUE...

Comment: Thanks, @Gabriel. Look forward to your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the product. It was initially meant as a solution to avoid recalculation of discounts when you use the copy/paste feature, but it also affected the use of web services with this screen. There's simply no way to force it to FALSE - system will also put TRUE in the field.

We have already fixed the problem internally, and the fix will be available in builds starting from 5.20.1071.

Answer (score 0):

```
            SO301000Content SO301000 = context.SO301000GetSchema();
        context.SO301000Clear();            

        try
        {
            SO301000Content[] SO301000Content = context.SO301000Submit(
                new Command[]
                {
                    SO301000.Actions.Insert,
                    new Value { Value = "SO", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType },                        
                    new Value { Value = "='new'", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr },
                    new Value { Value = "ABARTENDE", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Customer },                    
                    //new Value { Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Date },
                    new Value { Value = "this is a test order", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Description },

                    SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
                    new Value {Value = "CPU00001", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID},
                    new Value {Value = "RETAIL", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Warehouse},
                    new Value {Value = "BOX", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.UOM},
                    new Value {Value = "1", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity},                        
                    new Value {Value = "False", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.ManualDiscount },
                    new Value {Value = "1.01", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.UnitPrice, Commit = true },

                    SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
                    new Value {Value = "CPU00004", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID},
                    new Value {Value = "RETAIL", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Warehouse},
                    new Value {Value = "BOX", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.UOM},
                    new Value {Value = "2", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity},
                    new Value {Value = "False", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.ManualDiscount},
                    new Value {Value = "2.02", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.UnitPrice, Commit = true},

                    SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
                    new Value {Value = "CPU00008", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID},
                    new Value {Value = "RETAIL", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Warehouse},
                    new Value {Value = "PC", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.UOM},
                    new Value {Value = "3", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity},                   
                    new Value {Value = "False", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.ManualDiscount},
                    new Value {Value = "3.03", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.UnitPrice, Commit = true},                        

                    SO301000.Actions.Save,                  
                    SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr                                  
                }
            );
            Console.WriteLine(SO301000Content[0].OrderSummary.OrderNbr.Value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Comment: In terms of assigning "False" to "ManulDiscount", @srodionov, I think our code is same but it didn't work for me, is there anything else I did wrong?

Comment: I just tried your code just in case but didn't have luck  and your code didn't work for me either - I still see the "Manual Discount" checkbox is checked after the sales order was completed, even though I assigned "False" to "ManualDiscount" as shown in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I clarified regarding this checkbox.

well, when you use API or Copy-Paste methods this checkbox will always has value - true, it's by design.

I suggest to use second call to remove this values and/or set proper discount code.

Comment: If that is true, it would mean there is no way to get discount automatically applied without explicitly passing discount code or percentage through API. Yeah...I could do that by making change on my e-commerce site but it's kind of annoying - is there a reason why it was designed to behave in API differently from it does on screen?

Comment: @Gladiator this is also what I just figured out by tracing the code.

Comment: @srodionov, what is the reason? I don't understand why we want to have this behaviour. Second call will not do it, as this code runs in RowUpdated and forces it to manual in all cases.

Comment: We discussed internally and agreed it's a bug. We'll fix it so that it works properly when using web services - internal reference is AC-57263.